# Sitecore GraphQL query - custom image prefix

Tags: jss, graphql

Currently I have a GrahpQL query with bunch of images returning src as "/-/media"

query:

```
field(name:"Image"){ ...on ImageField{src} }
```

Result:

```
"Image": {
        "src": "/-/media/images/abc.ashx",
      },
```

Is there a way to get custom media prefix (without ~ or -. Just like "/customname/images...")?

Comment: The result you are receiving is the proper path for Sitecore to resolve it. If you want to change that to a custom path you may need to look into a solution involving a CDN.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelWest. Unfortunately we don't have a CDN setup.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have a CDN url setup. I created this patch file and now I am getting results as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"> 
<sitecore> 
 <settings> 
  <setting name="Media.RequestExtension"> 
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute> 
  </setting> 
  <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix"> 
   <patch:attribute name="value">customname</patch:attribute> 
  </setting> 
 </settings> 
 <customHandlers> 
  <handler trigger="/customname/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx"/> 
 </customHandlers> 
</sitecore> 
</configuration>
```

Now I am getting below results:

```
"Image": {
            "src": "/customname/images/abc.jpg",
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `zz.CDN.enabler.config` with the following settings to enable the CDN.

```
<setting name="Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl" value="true"/>
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkServerUrl" value="[you need to put the CDN url]"/>
<setting name="Media.AlwaysAppendRevision" value="false"/>
<setting name="MediaResponse.Cacheability" value="Public"/>
<setting name="MediaResponse.MaxAge" value="7.00:00:00"/>
```

and then `web.config` add the following setting it gives media urls a relevant extension like .jpg

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value=""/>
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjay and Sumit. Unfortunately we don't have CDN url setup.